# MS-SQL List of email addresses LIKE statement/regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, parsing, sql-like

I have a column in my table called `TO` which is a comma separated list of email addresses. (1-n)

I am not concerned with a row if it ONLY contains addresses to *Whatever@mycompany.com* and want to flag that as 0. However, if a row contains a NON mycompany address (even if there are mycompany addresses present) I'd like to flag it as 1. Is this possible using one LIKE statement?

I've tried;

```
AND
    [To]  like '%@%[^m][^y][^c][^o][^m][^p][^a][^n][^y]%.%'
```

The ideal output will be:

```
alice@mycompany.com, bob@mycompany.com, malory@yourcompany.com     1
alice@mycompany.com, bob@mycompany.com                             0
malory@yourcompany.com                                             1
```

Would it be better to write some kind of parsing function to split out addresses into a table if this isnt possible? I don't have an exhaustive list of other domains in the data.

Comment: Why don't you have a table that that maps email addresses to the current table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly but it works. Case statement compares number of occurences of @ symbol with number of occurences of @mycompany.com (XXX.. is just for keeping the length of the string):

```
select 
    * 
    , flag = case when len(field) - len(replace(replace(field,'@mycompany.com','XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),'@','')) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
from (
    select 'alice@mycompany.com, bob@mycompany.com, malory@yourcompany.com' as field union all 
    select 'alice@mycompany.com, bob@mycompany.com' union all 
    select 'malory@yourcompany.com' 
) x
```

Comment: Gosh thats a good idea! I should have thought of that. Looking at these tables for too long :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a simple counting approach.  Count the number of times that "@mycompany" appears and count the number of commas.  If these differ, then you have an issue:

```
 select emails,
        (case when len(emails) - len(replace(emails, ',', '')) = 
                   len(emails) - len(replace(emails, '@mycompany.com', 'mycompany.com'))
              then 0
              else 1
         end) as HasNonCompanyEmail
 from t
```

To simplify the arithmetic, I replace "@mycompany.com" with "mycompany.com".  This removes exactly one character.